# Ensuring constant animation speed regardless of FPS in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm getting started with PyGame. Coming with (some) Unity knowledge, I am used to multiplying my movement amounts by Time.timeDelta, which normalizes the movement speed. However, if I do this:

```
delta = clock.tick(x)
circle.move(delta)
pygame.display.flip()
```

If I time how long it takes the circle to get to its destination, I will get inconsistent results across different values of x. at 10 FPS it takes roughly 5.75 seconds, whereas at 60 - over 8 seconds.

How do I ensure my movement speed and get a good time delta?

Comment: Multiply movements and animations by how much time elapsed since the last frame, and make sure that your timer is accurate enough to make it meaningful to do this (pygame should have one that is good enough) http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ http://www.pygame.org/wiki/ConstantGameSpeed?parent=CookBook

Comment: @Patashu I'm sorry, but this thing is a little difficult for me to understand. Can you outline the solution, roughly?

Comment: If the linked information is 'too difficult for you to understand', I suggest you meditate it on it until it is not, because it is quite important to understand. Or you can ask specific questions you have.

Comment: Here is a more involved python example: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/ConstantGameSpeed?parent=CookBook ; And Delta should be the change in last time to current time. In your code you just grab current time.

Comment: try `clock.tick_busy_loop(x)`, it's more stable.Also, can you post the code for the move method?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps due to truncating coordinates. If you are tuncating coordinates, at 60 fps you are tuncating a lot more times than at 10 fps, so the movement could be slower.

In such a case, if you round coordinates you could achieve closer results.

Another solution could be keep coordinates as floats, so you calculate the movements using the stored floats as base, then you round to draw the sprite in int coordinates.

Comment: They are stored internally as floats.

Comment: Ok, just another guess, are you making any divisions? If your division only involve int values you get an integer division.

Answer (score 0):

You basically multiply the thing by the thing... e.g. if you are moving at 60fps... compared to 10 fps... you want to times the speed of the 10 fps by 6

Answer (score -1):

All that you should need to do is do circle.move(x), where x is the space you want it to move.
This way, FPS should not be a problem to you, it will move the distance regardless.

Just my guess, sorry if this doesn't work.

-Pip